# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' while using google-cloud-vision api

Tags: python, google-vision

i ran the following code

```
import io
import os
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath('resources/wakeupcat.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

the error i get is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\coding\pythonfolder\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

the library is installed is the following

```
pip install google-cloud-vision
```

I am fairly new to the google vision api so maybe there's some point I am missing
kindly let me know what the issue is, I tried pip install `--upgrade google-cloud-vision` as well but does not seems to work
my python version is `Python 3.10.0`
kindly let me know if there's any issue or missing information in my question
thank you!!

Comment: Please make sure your `pip` is installing for your interpreter version. Good ways to do that are using a virtual environment or running like `python -m pip …` with the same `python` as you run your code.

Comment: I am using pycharm

Comment: Pycharm has a terminal as well.

Comment: @KlausD. thank you I got it to work. I reinstalled pycharm, there was some missing python library, so reinstalling helped my avoid all errors, anyhow thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you messed up with the `venv`, since it worked fine for me. Try using PyCharm (if you don't already do) and setup a `venv`, or install `virtualenv` and launch these commands inside your project folder:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install google-cloud-vision
python your_file.py
deactivate
```

Last one is to properly exit the `venv`